# Ideas of Causality in ISLAM

Tags: islamic-philosophy, science, time

Currently I am working on a philosophy paper, exploring the correlation  between cause and effect, or in other words how present knowledge is wholly dependent upon past knowledge.

I was thinking of applying some reference or explanation based on Islam. Is there anything I can talk about, with respect to the hadiths or maybe something from the Quran with regards to the past and present dependency?

Comment: Allah (ﷻ) said he "taught man that which he knew not" (Qur'an 96:5). So all of our present knowledge is dependent upon and builds upon that which Allah (ﷻ) taught us in the beginning. SubhanAllah.

Answer (score 0):

How is present knowledge wholly dependent upon past knowledge?

Because the knowledge is in God, the Eternal. We achieve knowledge according to His will:

Quran 2:255:

> God: there is no deity save Him, the Living, the Eternal
> One. Neither slumber nor sleep overtakes Him. To Him belong whatsoever
> is in the heavens and whatsoever is on the earth. Who can intercede
> with Him except by His permission? He knows all that is before them
> and all that is behind them. They can grasp only that part of His
> knowledge which He wills. His throne extends over the heavens and the
> earth; and their upholding does not weary Him. He is the Sublime, the
> Almighty One!

And He wills:

Quran 96:1-5

> Read: In the Name of your Lord who created. (1) Created man from a
> clot. (2) Read: And your Lord is the Most Generous. (3) He who taught
> by the pen. (4) Taught man what he never knew. (5)

Knowledge of menkind is growing through God:

Quran 2:31

> And He taught Adam the names - all of them.

Quran 3:48

> And He will teach him writing and wisdom and the Torah and the Gospel.

Quran 3:3-4

> He sent down to you the Book with the Truth, confirming what came before it; and He sent down the Torah and the Gospel. (3) Aforetime, as guidance for mankind; and He sent down the Criterion.

A growth of knowledge is there. But the main Islamic philosophy (also Christian philosophy) is that past and present and future are present in God.